# How does Visual Studio's UnderWare Brief commands emulation compare to Emacs and normal Edit?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, ide

Visual Studio (the *full-fat* version, not Visual Studio Code) and SQL Server Management Studio both feature editing commands that emulate (replicate? reimplement?) [UnderWare Brief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brief_(text_editor)) and [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) (but [not Vim, hmpf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war)!)

In the IDE's Tools > Options > Keyboard Shortcuts window, the Brief-emulation commands have the prefix `Edit.Brief...` and the Emacs-emulation commands have the prefix `Edit.Emacs...`:

[image: Screenshot of VS's keyboard command bindings]

I was setting up some custom shortcuts of mine (as I like to bind <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> to `Edit.LineDelete` and <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to `Edit.Duplicate`), and I noticed that the IDE has seemingly duplicate functionality from the Brief and Emacs emulation commands, which made me wonder what the difference was.

Unfortunately there's no documentation available online that describes exactly how each `Edit.*` command differs from each other - I know I could dive through VS' editor's DLLs to try to find out but before losing a weekend down a rabbit-hole I thought to ask first...

So, can someone explain the differences between these similarly-named commands?

| Normal | UnderWare Brief | Emacs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Edit.BreakLine` | `Edit.BriefBreakLine` | `Edit.EmacsBreakLine` |
| `Edit.LineDelete` | `Edit.BriefLineDelete` |  |
| `Edit.DeleteToEOL` | `Edit.BriefLineDeleteToEnd` | `Edit.EmacsDeleteToEOL` |
| `Edit.DeleteToBOL` | `Edit.BriefLineDeleteToStart` |  |
| `Edit.Find` | `Edit.BriefFind` |  |
| `Edit.Replace` | `Edit.BriefFindReplace` | `Edit.EmacsFindReplace` |
| `Edit.WordDeleteToEnd` | `Edit.BriefWordDeleteToEnd` | `Edit.EmacsWordDeleteToEnd` |
| `Edit.WordDeleteToStart` | `Edit.BriefWordDeleteToStart` | `Edit.EmacsWordDeleteToStart` |
| `Edit.WordPrevious` | `Edit.BriefWordLeft` | `Edit.EmacsWordPrevious` |
| `Edit.WordNext` | `Edit.BriefWordRight` | `Edit.EmacsWordNext` |

Additionally, what *exactly* does `Edit.WordNextExtend` and `Edit.WordNextExtendColumn` do?

Comment: I had/continue to have very similar queries! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70489299/visual-studio-ide-difference-between-commands-that-differ-slightly

I have raised an official issue here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/7470

Let us hope something comes out of it!

Comment: @Tryer Thank you for filing that issue. Can you add a link to this QA from your GitHub issue? Thanks