# Visual Studio IDE: Difference between commands that differ slightly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Officially, the commands list for Visual Studio IDE available at:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio.md

does not seem to be doing a good job of explaining what different commands *actually do*.

For instance, what is the difference between:

- Edit.BreakLine and Edit.BriefBreakLine
- Window.PreviousDocumentWindow and  Window.PreviousDocumentWindowNav

?

There are many many other commands that differ from each other very slightly and the user is completely at a loss to figure these differences out on his own.

The specific examples mentioned above are all command IDs either mentioned on the above webpage or else are available in Visual Studio. The explanation for these command IDs on the webpage is purportedly the column titled "Command" but this just repeats the command IDs which are already in English.

Is there any place/website/resource where one could understand visually with examples what these plethora of commands actually accomplish and how they differ from each other?

Comment: The question body of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053610/how-does-visual-studios-underware-brief-commands-emulation-compare-to-emacs-and seems to answer your first. In most cases, you need to build up experiments to see what exactly a certain command does. I don't expect Microsoft to have a detailed article on such.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have raised an issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/7470

Let us see if it has any effect! Given my past experience, they simply redirect queries back to stackoverflow!